# Uncaught ReferenceError: suppliers is not defined, return js from a script to a secondary page

Tags: javascript

As a proof that my data is correct and loading from it's original source, I dump out the data directly in the `supplier.js` script as a sanity check.

**supplier.js**

```
        }).then((response) => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
            }
            return response.json();
        }).then((data) => {
            let suppliers = data.suppliers;
            // return suppliers;
            console.log(suppliers);
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }
}

const supplier = new Supplier();
const suppliers = supplier.getSuppliers();
```

an array of data, perfect!

[image]

It's a different story in `dashboard.php` meanwhile, I just get `undefined`?

**dashboard.php**

```
<script src="/js/supplier.js"></script>

<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        console.log(suppliers);
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Should be straightforward but, I keep getting undefined?

[image]

Comment: You need to process the values where you console.log them in the .then: `}).then((data) => { processSuppliers(data.suppliers); }`